# RxJava Subject with Backpressure - only let the last value emit once downstream has finished consuming

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a PublishSubject that calls `onNext()` on some UI event. The subscriber usually takes 2 seconds to complete its job. I need to ignore all calls to `onNext()` except the last one while the subscriber is busy. I tried the following, however I'm unable to control the flow. The requests seem to get queued up and each and every request gets processed (and so back pressure isn't seemingly working). How can I make it ignore all requests but the last one? (I don't want to use `debounce` as the code needs to react immediately and any reasonably small timeout won't work).

Moreover I realize using `subscribeOn` with a subject has no effect, thus I'm using `observeOn` to do async work in one of the operators. Is this the correct approach?

```
Subject<Boolean> loadingQueue = PublishSubject.<Boolean>create().toSerialized();

loadingQueue
  .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .map(discarded -> {
    // PRE-LOADING
    Log.d("RXLOADING", "PRE-LOADING: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return discarded;
   })
   .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
   .map(b -> {
     Log.d("RXLOADING", "LOADING: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
     Thread.sleep(2000);
     return b;
   })
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(b -> {
      Log.d("RXLOADING", "FINISHED: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\n\n");
   });


loadingQueue.onNext(true);
loadingQueue.onNext(true);
loadingQueue.onNext(true);
....
```

The output I see is:

```
PRE-LOADING: main
PRE-LOADING: main
LOADING: RxComputationThreadPool-1
PRE-LOADING: main
PRE-LOADING: main
PRE-LOADING: main
PRE-LOADING: main
PRE-LOADING: main
PRE-LOADING: main
LOADING: RxComputationThreadPool-1
FINISHED: main
LOADING: RxComputationThreadPool-1
FINISHED: main
LOADING: RxComputationThreadPool-1
FINISHED: main
LOADING: RxComputationThreadPool-1
FINISHED: main
LOADING: RxComputationThreadPool-1
FINISHED: main
LOADING: RxComputationThreadPool-1
FINISHED: main
LOADING: RxComputationThreadPool-1
FINISHED: main
FINISHED: main
```

Instead I expect the code to do the following (i.e. load once, and while it's loading, back-pressure to hold back on all requests and emit the last one, once the first observer has finished - so in total it should ideally only load twice at most):

```
PRE-LOADING: main
LOADING: RxComputationThreadPool-1
FINISHED: main

PRE-LOADING: main
LOADING: RxComputationThreadPool-1
FINISHED: main
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this with `observeOn` because it will buffer at least 1 element and thus always execute the "PRE-LOADING" stage if there is already one "LOADING" happening.

However you can do it with `delay` as it doesn't manipulate request amounts on the chain and schedules each onNext individually on the scheduler without queueing it on its own:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Subject<Boolean> loadingQueue = 
         PublishSubject.<Boolean>create().toSerialized();

    loadingQueue
      .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
      .delay(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.single())        // <-------
      .map(discarded -> {
        // PRE-LOADING
        System.out.println("PRE-LOADING: " 
             + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return discarded;
       })
       .delay(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.computation())  // <-------
       .map(b -> {
           System.out.println("LOADING: " 
             + Thread.currentThread().getName());
         Thread.sleep(2000);
         return b;
       })
       .delay(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.single())       // <-------
       .rebatchRequests(1)             // <----------------------------------- one-by-one
       .subscribe(b -> {
           System.out.println("FINISHED: " 
               + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\n\n");
       });


    loadingQueue.onNext(true);
    loadingQueue.onNext(true);
    loadingQueue.onNext(true);

    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: That works beautifully, thank you so much. I must admit, I would never have been able to come up with this. I will now have to study delay and rebatchRequests in more detail.

Comment: @akarnokd i was curious, i found that replacing the first `observeOn` in the original code with `observeOn(Schedulers.single(), false, 1)` results in the same behavior - is this a valid alternative solution, or is there some downside of doing it this way? thanks!

Comment: If the items were distinguishable then yes; it would store item #2 while the latest runs ahead to item #N. When the processing finishes at the end, a new request will process item #2 and the first observeOn will then store item #N. You won't get the latest but some time snapshots.

Comment: @akarnokd   please help me achieving same but instead of getting the last event i want all the event which was happen while the subscriber is busy in previous events/event(in case a single event)

Comment: Just use `BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER`.