# RxJava Subject with Backpressure - let the whole list to emit once downstream has finished consuming

Tags: android, rx-java2

i have a same question like this one [RxJava Subject with Backpressure - only let the last value emit once downstream has finished consuming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958423/rxjava-subject-with-backpressure-only-let-the-last-value-emit-once-downstream)  but instead i want all the items which emitted (list of all the buffered items) while the downstream is busy in consuming

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Subject<Boolean> loadingQueue = 
                 PublishSubject.<Boolean>create().toSerialized();

loadingQueue
  .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
  .delay(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.single())        // <-------
  .map(discarded -> {
    // PRE-LOADING
    System.out.println("PRE-LOADING: " 
         + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return discarded;
   })
   .delay(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.computation())  // <-------
   .map(b -> {
       System.out.println("LOADING: " 
         + Thread.currentThread().getName());
     Thread.sleep(2000);
     return b;
   })
   .delay(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.single())       // <-------
   .rebatchRequests(1)             // <-----------------------------------  one-by-one
   .subscribe(b -> {
       System.out.println("FINISHED: " 
           + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\n\n");
   });


loadingQueue.onNext(true);
loadingQueue.onNext(true);
loadingQueue.onNext(true);

Thread.sleep(10000);
```

}

it working but instead of getting item one by one i want list of all the buffered item at once  and while downstream busy i want to create another list and so on

Comment: I'm sorry, this requires a non-trivial custom operator.

Comment: @akarnokd what do you think the solution below is fine or some other cases need to handle ??

Comment: I'm not sure if you'd get the same PRE-LOADING and FINISHED pattern but if it works for you then go ahead with it. Also please avoid cross posting - it has likely no benefit because I'm going to answer on the RxJava issue list as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to achieve items emitted in the form of list when some event happen and start another list till other event happen

```
    Subject<Integer>  burstSubject =
        PublishSubject.<Integer>create().toSerialized(); 

     Subject<Integer> boundarySubject =
        PublishSubject.<Integer>create().toSerialized();


       Flowable.interval(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(value ->{

                burstSubject.onNext((int) (long)value);

      });




    burstSubject.buffer(boundarySubject)
     .subscribe(integers -> {

           Log.d(TAG, "total items "+integers.size());

    });

   //when some event come from UI or other source to get the list of
   //items emitted till now in the form of List

     fab.setOnClickListener(view -> {

        boundarySubject.onNext(++index); // ignore just for emits list from burstSubject

    }
```